# How to convert latitude and longitude in decimal to WGS84 coordinate?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, coordinates, coordinate-systems

I am trying to display a list of points on the map. but these latitude and longitude are given as decimals:

```
      index    X              y 
      1    24050.0000    123783.3333
      2    24216.6667    123933.3333
      3    24233.3333    123950.0000
      4    24233.3333    124016.6667 
         ........................
```

These data is taken from [sources](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/world/ja9847.tsp)([page](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/world/)). It seems I can use these data directly with Google Map API, so what should I do?

How can I convert them into a format compatible with Google Map API to display? I am using JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me those points are just the WGS84 coordinates multiplied by 1000. The code below gives me a reasonable location in Japan, where data is the [array of points in the file you reference](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/world/ja9847.tsp).

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  position: {
    lat: data[i][1] / 1000,
    lng: data[i][2] / 1000
  }
```

});

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/Lgq0atvo/)

[image: Japan points from data]

Comment: Thanks a million. why they just don't  say that on their web? I searched and read many, finally you saved me.